# What's the etymology behind this chess opening?

Tags: opening, terminology

This line is called the Brooklyn Variation of Alekhine's Defense:

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 Nf6 2. e5 Ng8!?
```

How did it get its name?

Comment: I doubt any serious chess player outside of US calls it "Brooklyn variation" though.

Comment: @sleepy I doubt any serious chess player considers this at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power of a Google search reveals: from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alekhine%27s_Defence#Brooklyn_Variation

> 2...Ng8, undeveloping the knight immediately, was named the "Brooklyn Defence" in honour of his hometown by GM Joel Benjamin, who calls this his "pet line".

Provided reference: Joel Benjamin, American Grandmaster: Four Decades of Chess Adventures, Gloucester Publishers, 2007, p. 167. ISBN 978-1-85744-552-7.